# нижняя рамка у UITextView

Tags: ios, swift

Чтобы добавить рамку `UITextField`, я использую код:

```
let line = CALayer()
line.borderColor = UIColor.blackColor().CGColor
line.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: field.frame.size.height - 1, width: field.frame.size.width*2, height: field.frame.size.height)
line.borderWidth = 1
field.layer.addSublayer(line)
```

Но если такой же использовать для `UITextView` - получается просто ужасно. А если ещё делать, чтобы поле при переходе на новую строку увеличивалось в размерах - эта линия остаётся на старом месте. Пробовал по разному решить этот вопрос (даже удаление sublayer`a у TextView и размещении его на новых координанах), но всегда получать всё очень криво. Есть ли какой-нибудь простой способ сделать такую простою задачу?

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте использовать собственный layer у UITextView:

```
textView.layer.borderColor = UIColor.blackColor().CGColor
textView.layer.borderWidth = 1.0
textView.layer.cornerRadius = 15.0
```

Comment: Да, тогда  рамка расширяется вместе с TextView, но проблема в том, что мне нужна рамка только внизу. То есть примерно это будет выглядеть, как в Material Design